# Find specific file in all drives and work with its path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files from Google drive into specific folder (LUTS) that contains the file (Old Noir.cube) because I am using shared PCs and this will save my morning time trying to get everything together.

Looking through the drives for the folder and trying to catch the directory into a variable ($path) so I can download the zip file and extract into it but I am making a mess and it did not work for me when I add `$path` in front of the `Get-ChildItem`

Hope someone can shed some light on this, thank you!

```
$AllDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
foreach ($drive in $AllDrives)
{
    $Path = Get-ChildItem -path $drive.Root -recurse -include "Old Noir.cube" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "LUTS"} | Select Directory
}
```

Current progress based on the first answer from KUTlime.

I am creating few .ps files to download different file formats, please let me know if there is a more 'sophisticated' way of doing this.

```
$Paths = @()
# Loop through system drives to look for x folder containing x file 
$AllDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
foreach ($drive in $AllDrives)
{
    $Paths += (Get-ChildItem -path $drive.Root -recurse -include "Old Noir.cube" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                    Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "LUTS"} | Foreach-Object {$_.Directory.FullName} )
}

# Show menu if more than 1 result returned
$Selection = $Paths | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Select valid path from the list then click OK"
if ($Selection) {
    "You picked $Selection"
} else {
    "Cancelled"
}

# Download a zip file
# $source = "http://www.mediafire.com/file/Nov.zip"
# $target = "$Selection\tool.zip"

# Download a 7z file
$source = "http://www.mediafire.com/file/Nov.7z"
$target = "$Selection\tool.7z"

# Check if Invoke-Webrequest exists otherwise execute WebClient
if (Get-Command 'Invoke-Webrequest')
{
        Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $target
}
else
{
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target)
}

# Zip
#Expand-Archive -Path $target -DestinationPath $Selection -Verbose

# 7zip
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
# Hide output with > $null
& ${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe x $target "-o$($Selection)" -y > $null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your `$Path` with `null` at the end during the last iteration.

Change your code to something like this:

```bsh
$Paths = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
$AllDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
foreach ($drive in $AllDrives)
{
    $Paths.Add(Get-ChildItem -path $drive.Root -recurse -include "Old Noir.cube" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "LUTS"} | Select Directory)
}
```

or

```bsh
$Paths = @()
$AllDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
foreach ($drive in $AllDrives)
{
    $Paths += Get-ChildItem -path $drive.Root -recurse -include "Old Noir.cube" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "LUTS"} | Select Directory)
}
```